# How to free Non DFS Used space with Hortonworks hdp SSH client?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using HDP for self-study to learn Big data basics. Today I've faced the following: HDFS disk usage is 91%. With Non DFS Used 31.2 GB / 41.6 GB (74.96%).

[image]
What exactly should I do to free disk space? Is it possible to do from sandbox hdp SSH client? I'm running HPD on a Virtual box.

I've executed the command from sandbox hdp SSH client: `hdfs dfs -du -h /` But this is obviously HDFS data usage.

```
12.2 M   /app-logs
1.5 G    /apps
0        /ats
860.9 K  /demo
724.4 M  /hdp
0        /livy2-recovery
0        /mapred
0        /mr-history
479.6 M  /ranger
176.6 K  /spark2-history
0        /tmp
4.0 G    /user
0        /webhdfs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just treat this like any other disk almost full issue.

Login to the sandbox.  Run `du -s /*/*` to see what is using up disk space.  I suspect it's probably the log files (under `/var/log/*`).